# Where can I find a ski touring guide book for the Patagonia region?

Tags: guidebooks, patagonia, skiing

Does anybody know of a guide book for ski touring in Patagonia? Covering the areas of Bariloche, El Calafate and Ushuaia. Preferably in English, but Spanish would do too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a book called "[Patagonia: The Andes, a Guide For Climbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0182FT2G2)" by John Biggar.

Its main focus is climbing, but also covers **ski-mountaineering**:

> This new edition has expanded coverage of the whole range, with many
>   new photos and route diagrams plus extended coverage of the
>   ski-mountaineering opportunities in the Andes.The book contains
>   details of how to climb all 100 of the major 6000m peaks in the Andes,
>   plus route information for approximately 300 other peaks. There are
>   over 240 route diagrams, 150 additional photos and 80 sketch maps.

which is likely going to cover the more adventurous among us, seemingly like yourself.